# How to filter and display packets based on a specific info using Wireshark?

Tags: mqtt, wireshark

I want to filter from the captured file based on a specific info (for example, Publish Message [posmsg2] or Publish Message [posblock2]) using Wireshark. This is because I want to know how many packets with Publish Message [posmsg2] Info or how many packets with Publish Message [posblock2] separately.

How to filter and display the filtered data only?

[image]

Comment: How is the screenshot you've provided not doing what you asked for?

Comment: @hardillb there are some information that I don't want like Ping Request and Ping Response. I edited my question.

Comment: I forget the syntax, but your display filter will express "the message type is not ping and the message type is not ping-response".  There will be some specific name, depending on the protocol, to get to the type field. I assume you've read the [documentation](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters)?

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, the required filtering variables; posblovk2 and posmsg2 , are in the "info" section of the Wireshark log. Hence do a filtering of the info section instead of typing"mqtt"

Comment: While it is possible to filter packets based on information contained in the Info column, it is **not** currently possible to do so without a Lua script such as [filtcols.lua](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/Lua/Examples/filtcols), so this requires an extra step instead of simply applying the `mqtt contains posmsg2` display filter directly, as @ismsm discovered.

Answer (score 0):

I used this syntax to show only Publish Message [posmsg2] `mqtt contains posmsg2`.
based on [this reference](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters)